# Jquery DataTable Group Sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using Jquery DataTable (https://datatables.net/) plugin and have grouped the rows based on column0. The groups that are generated are in Alphabetical order by default, but I would like to make these groups order according to my need. Is there a way to do this? I saw this documentation (https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customGroupOrdering.html) but it is asking to write HTML for each row. Not sure if thats the right way. Can someone know how to go about this?

Thanks
Anmol

Answer (score 0):

The grouping functionality provides sorting based on the jquery code suggested in https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customGroupOrdering.html.

You can modify the sorting method as per your need and use it:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable().rowGrouping({
        iGroupingColumnIndex: 1,
        sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",
        iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 0
    });
});
```